# How do I manage dofollow and nofollow in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, nofollow

I mean when I set link in my website to new tab it automatically set to rel="noreferrer noopener". 
I want to set this links open in new tab but in dofollow.
Also I need help with this can I get both option dofollow or nofollow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link example provided is a dofollow link, as that is the default for a hyperlink.
    noreferrer noopener 
still passes the 'dofollow' over, it just doesn't send the referral header (so it seems like direct traffic).

Comment: it means rel="noreferrer noopener is dofollow ?

Comment: This tag when combined basically means that no referrer information should be passed to the website being linked (noreferrer) to and noopener prevents the newly opened page from having the ability to control the page that delivered the traffic.

It doesn't impact the 'follow' status.